# jquery - How to make dialog button wait response from another dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

**Update 1: I've done with callback function.** 
This is my solution. I just add a callback function when open dialog2 and a hidden element to receive what user change in dialog 2. Now everything done. Thanks you!

http://jsfiddle.net/N6qbR/2/

-------Old question----------------

My English is bad so I write easily.

I'm using Jquery Dialog and I want to show multiple dialogs. (dialog1 opens dialog2 opens dialog 3...)

But the problem is when I open dialog1 and then dialog2 (confirm dialog, So that the user can choose Yes/No in dialog2 and return value to dialog1).

I know Javascript is asynchronous, so when user opens dialog1 and click open dialog2, it won't wait for event in dialog2 to finish.

[Here is my source code](http://jsfiddle.net/juRm9/2) (simple logic)

```
$("#dialogForm").dialog({           
        autoOpen: false,
        height: height,
        width: width,
        modal: true,        
        close: function() // Hàm này được gọi tự động khi đóng dialog
        {           
            //abc();
            // Sau khi thêm mới thành công thì reset lại form
            resetForm();
            $("#dialogForm").dialog( "close" );
        },          
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function() {              
                var choose = showDialogConfirm(250, 200, "Bạn có đồng ý thêm?", test);      
                if(choose == true)
                {
                    // do some good
                }

            },
            "Cancel": function() {
                $("#dialogForm").dialog("close");
            }
        }
    }); 


    $("#dialogForm").dialog("open");

function showDialogConfirm(width, height, message)
{
    $("#dialogConfirm").toggle();           
    $("#dialogConfirm").dialog({            
        autoOpen: false,
        height: height,
        width: width,
        modal: true,        
        close: function() // Hàm này được gọi tự động khi đóng dialog
        {           
            $("#dialogConfirm").dialog( "close" );
        },          
        buttons: {
            "Yes": function() {         
                return true;
                $("#dialogConfirm").dialog("close");
            },
            "No": function() {
                return false;
                $("#dialogConfirm").dialog("close");                    
            }
        }
    });

    $("#dialogConfirmContent").html(message);   
    $("#dialogConfirm") 
        .dialog("open");
}
```

Comment: javascript is not asynchronous.

Comment: your fiddle does not work at all

Comment: This is simple logic :) and it cannot work.

Comment: @charlietfl I'm sure you know what the OP means (that the dialog is not synchronous) and you're just trying to be extra picky.

Comment: @JuanMendes events that trigger dialog are synchronous, not sure what you mean that they aren't. The dialog elements are always existing also in OP case

Comment: please don't have mistake in your conversation. I've done with this. I think javascript is synchronous. When a dialog open, it will wait until user close it. But if another dialog open from this, it is ansyncrhonous. That's why javascript has a callback function from parrent to wait until child stops working. I think so :)

Answer (score 0):

definitely you should write the code in the dialog `callback functions`. in the `dialog1` that you just pop up the `dialog2` and cuz it's confirm dialog, so it should be model dialog and you bind the code to the `OK button`, then you can `get` the "correct" result. Change the `showconfirmdialog` by adding a new parameter: `callbackfunction`.

Comment: thanks but could you give me how to make a callbackfunction? I'm newbie with Jquery.

Comment: I've searched about callback function. Thanks your idea. I'll try.

Comment: sorry buddy, I'm in China, you know I'am sleeping. It should be like this. showdialog(x,x,callbackfunc). then in the dialog that button: ok: function(){callbackfunc()}; all most like this.